# java - JPA EntityManager Injection fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get my homework done, in which I have to build a Restful Webservice with Spring. In addition I am using the JPA (Eclipselink) to edit, search and show database entries.

My persistence.xml is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="test">
        <class>at.test.entities.UserEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://myserver:3306/somedatabase"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I try to get an entityManager via

```
entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test").createEntityManager();
```

it works just fine but if I want to do it via the `@PersistenceContext` annotation

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestHandler': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'test' is defined
```

How it works:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class RequestHandler {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserTest> test(@RequestParam(value = "asd", defaultValue = "") String name) {
        /* works just fine */
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test").createEntityManager();

        /* Some test stuff */
        UserTest user = entityManager.find(UserTest.class, 1);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(new UserTest("ASDASD", "ASDASdjnwco2eno2oc"));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return new ResponseEntity<UserTest>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

How it does not work:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class RequestHandler {
    /* Does not work */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserTest> test(@RequestParam(value = "asd", defaultValue = "") String name) {
        /* Some test stuff */
        UserTest user = entityManager.find(UserTest.class, 1);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(new UserTest("ASDASD", "ASDASdjnwco2eno2oc"));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return new ResponseEntity<UserTest>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

**Solution**

Both solutions, the one from AdrianDuta and Branislav Lazic works. You can either define your beans and persistence Unit via an XML File or configuring them per Java-Class.

Although I now used this template/example:

[spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate)

Comment: Can you paste the Spring-JPA Configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@PersistenceContext` you are injecting `EntityManager` bean into your rest controller. To make it work, you can define [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html)

```
@Bean(name = "test")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        // configuration here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

define in you applicationContext:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test" />
</bean>



<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```